# Statically checking node.js import references

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just did a big refactor, and I want to check that I didn't accidentally write:

```
tools.extractConversation
```

or:

```
integrations.extractConversation
```

or:

```
routes.extractConversation
```

instead of

```
helpers.extractConversation
```

since extractConversation is in fact in the helpers module, and make a similar confirmation for a bunch more methods. However, lots of the calls the various methods I want to check are buried deep in other methods which I don't want to call.

Are there tools to statically do this check? I'm not trying to check that I made the correct decision to call `helpers.foo` rather than `tools.foo`, only that they're all defined.

(in b4 "Have a proper testing framework, moron")

Comment: What speaks against a simple text search in the code? You could even set up a scheduled job for that. If you use some VCS, it could also be integrated into the commit trigger.

Comment: Because it's not a simple search. There's M methods and N modules, and I want to ensure that a given method is referencing the correct module.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want to ensure that it's always `helpers.extractConversation` which is called. If that's true, a regExp search could be used. Otherwise I might have misunderstood your example: Did you rather mean to make sure that the called procedure should always be checked against the "referenced module" to ensure it does exist there? If so: there still could be methods with the same name in different modules, which still might leave some "wrong addressing" undiscovered.

Comment: I'm not trying to check that I made the correct decision to call `helpers.foo` rather than `tools.foo`, only that they're all defined. Doing this with regex search is a terrible idea because I'd need to write a script to generate MxN specific regexes. I could do it, but I have priorities.

Comment: So, you basically want to search all your code to test if it would be runnable (thus checking you made all imports correct)?

Comment: Yes, that's right.